# How I can retrieve a DBPedia page that start with "http://fr.dbpedia.org"

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, dbpedia, linked-data

I have a DBPedia resource as

> http://dbpedia.org/page/London

.
I would like to get French page of http://dbpedia.org/page/London using SPARQL. I have noticed that I can retrieve this information through owl:sameAs.

I am trying to write this query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint to retrieve http://fr.dbpedia.org/page/Londres page:

```
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
select ?resource where {
?resource owl:sameAs "http://dbpedia.org/page/London"
FILTER strStarts (?resource, "http://fr.dbpedia.org")
```

In particular, I thought to use `"strStarts"` property, because I have read this document: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts.
This document says that "The STRSTARTS function corresponds to the XPath fn:starts-with function" and I thought to use this function to retrieve the triples that start with "http://fr.dbpedia.org".

But, from my query I don't get any result. Why?
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems in your query.  First, URIs are not strings, so you'd need to use `<http://dbpedia.org/page/London>` rather than `"http://dbpedia.org/page/London"`.  Second, that's the wrong URI for London.  The resource is `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/London>`. (Yes, when you put that in a web browser, you get redirected to the `…/page/London`;  that's not the URI of the resource, though.)  The URI can be abbreviated as `dbpedia:London` on the public endpoint.  Third, because URIs are not strings, you need to `filter strstarts( str(?resource), … )`, explicitly getting the string form of the URI.  Thus:

```
select ?resource where {
  ?resource owl:sameAs dbpedia:London
  filter strstarts(str(?resource), "http://fr.dbpedia.org")
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fresource%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fresource%20owl%3AsameAs%20dbpedia%3ALondon%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strStarts%28str%28%3Fresource%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffr.dbpedia.org%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Ok thanks, it works! I thought that "http://dbpedia.org/page/London" also was a URI because I wrote it in my browser to search this page.

Comment: @Musich87 `http://dbpedia.org/page/London` is certainly a URI, it's just not the one that identifies the London DBpedia resource.